# Are messages encrypted when sending from application to Azure IOT Hub over AMQP protocol? Is it SSL Secured?

Tags: encryption, amqp, azure-iot-hub

I am sending messages from my application to Azure IOT Hub over AMQP protocol. I am using Azure.Devices.Client sdk to send messages. I want to know whether the messages sent from the application are encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure IoT Hub only allows encrypted connections from devices. In order to establish an [encrypted connection to Azure IoTHub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-fundamentals/iot-security-ground-up#secure-connectivity)  - using industry-standard Transport Layer Security (TLS) - your [device needs to trust Baltimore Cybertrust Root CA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-tls-support#iot-hubs-server-tls-certificate).

Since you are using [Azure IoT Device SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks#azure-iot-hub-device-sdks), establishing an encrypted connection is built-in and as long as you have Baltimore CyberTrust Root on your Trusted Root Certification Authorities your application should just work.

[image: Baltimore CyberTrust Root on your Trusted Root Certification Authorities]

Comment: Auto retry policy should work for transient errors.

Comment: @asergaz Is there any method to perform Server SSL certificate authentication in client side? Regarding to the post: https://www.nixu.com/blog/remote-code-execution-vulnerability-microsoft-intune-managed-windows-devices, is it possible that a client connects to unexpected IoT hubs when DNS hijacking?